# GDB's "No symbol table is loaded" when trying to "strace"

Tags: linux, gdb, redhat, strace

I'm trying to `strace` a thread (or a process, for that matter) on the system through gdb, using `strace -p <pid>`.
I get the following message:

> No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
>
> Make static tracepoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])

I've seen solutions offering to use `file <file-name>`, but in my case, when I have no file to run, what do I have to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`strace`](https://strace.io/) you are looking for is a command-line tool, not a GDB command. Exit GDB to run it.